# How to always print out a last item in a tuple. (Python)

Tags: python

Is there a function in Python to do it?
I have tried printing out last item in the tuple, but each time I want to generate more strings, I have to change it manually.

Comment: like for a list get element at index -1, and print it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try tuple_name[-1]

replace tuple_name with your tuple name

finally, it will be like print(tuple_name[-1])

Comment: you probably mean `[-1]`rather than `(-1)`

Comment: You need square brackets. Parens are for function calls and you're going to get a syntax error with your code.

Comment: Oops it's my mistake, changed, thanks

Comment: Removed my downvote and upvoted as this is the correct answer. Even though this question is a dupe and will likely get closed.